# How to create a selector with "2 tabs" in acumatica

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

can someone please help me how to create a selector with 2 (All records, project codes) tabs like this.

[Image - Example of the selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU5wC.png)

I was looking on the internet but I did not find an example.

Additional.

My project is a customization.
The Screen id of reference is: PJ304000
Thank you very much I will appreciate any help

Comment: that's just a filter. you can create you own filtering and they'll be created as separate tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on rick, here is a order of operations:

First configure a filter
[image: First configure a filter]

Give it a name
[image: give it a name]

Save it, press apply and your filter is now a tab
[image: Save it, press apply and your filter is now a tab]